# Bandwidth monitor

Tags: vb.net

I am wanting to create an application that will monitor the upload/download traffic of a user. Can someone point me too some code that I can have a look at?

I have found SharpPcap - A Packet Capture Framework for .NET, but cannot find any vb.net code for it.

I have found this code:

```
    Dim Properties As IPGlobalProperties
    Dim StatV4 As IPGlobalStatistics
    Properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties
    StatV4 = Properties.GetIPv4GlobalStatistics
    Dim Packets As Long = StatV4.ReceivedPackets
```

What actually is a 'packet'? Can I calculate the download/upload from this code by maybe multiplying the recievedPackets by packet size... or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this project http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/dotnetwinpcap.aspx which is GPL licensed and you can browse code.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some good examples here [SharpPcap examples at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharppcap.aspx), but they are of course in C#. But it will be very trival to translate these examples from C# to VB.NET.

Comment: I have had a look at both those links. I cannot actually see any help for monitoring bandwidth usage, instead it is more about individual packets.

Comment: Another solution could be to use WMI to retreive number of sent and received bytes. WMI classes are placed in the `System.Management`. There are also many WMI samples at CodeProject you can use as a kick start.